# Non-invocable member '' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, opcode

I'm facing a problem right naw.
So i'll put the code right away;

```
public static List<ushort> blockedOpcodes = new List<ushort>();

    public static bool isOpcodeAllowed(ushort opcode)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (blockedOpcodes.Contains(opcode))
            {
                Log1.LogMsg("Oops! Someone tried to send a blocked packet: 0x{" + opcode + ":X}");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }


    public static void Load()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            StreamReader reader;
            using (reader = new StreamReader("filter.txt"))
            {
                string str = null;
                while ((str = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    blockedOpcodes.Add(Convert.ToUInt16(str));
                }
            }
            Log1.LogMsg("Opcode filter loaded!");
            using (reader = new StreamReader("specialip.txt"))
            {
                string item = null;
                while ((item = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    specialIPs.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So those are in a class called 'Program' What I'm trying to do is collect data 'opcodes' to block from 'blockedOpcodes'

```
if (Project_name.Program.blockedOpcodes(current.Opcode))
```

That's where the error shows up..

Error:

> Error 1   Non-invocable member 'Project_name.Program.blockedOpcodes'
>   cannot be used like a
>   method.   C:\Users\skipper\Desktop\Project_name\without\src2 -
>   Copy\Project_name\Clients.cs  584 63  Project_name

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!
PS: I'm a beginner in C# I have started like 7 days ago..

Comment: I would also remove the `lock` it's pointless

Comment: What data are you storing within the list? Where do you populate it?

Comment: opcodes.
example;
1001
1003
1004

Comment: See my second edit, I think this is what ypu´re looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously you need

```
if (Project_name.Program.blockedOpcodes[current.Opcode] != 0)
```

instead of this:

```
if (Project_name.Program.blockedOpcodes(current.Opcode))
```

Because `blockedOpcodes` is a list rather then a method.

EDIT: You need to compare your list-value against `0` (or whatever you consider to be an "invalid" value) because you store int-values within the list.

EDIT: To check if a given OpCode is within your list simply call this:

```
if (blockedOpcodes.Contains(current.Opcode)) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Another error showed up; 
Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'ushort' to 'bool' C:\Users\skipper\Desktop\Project_name\without\src2 - Copy\Project_name\Clients.cs 584 41 Project_name

Comment: @Skipper: That's because the List is of type `ushort` and you are using it as a `Boolean`. `if(something)` means `if something is true then do the following...`. So you need something to compare the value from `blockOpcodes` to.

Comment: `current.Opcode` is not a valid index and the list doesn't contain booleans.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Sure it is (a valid index), I edited the return value however

Comment: Obviously nonsense. You are doing `opcodes.Add(1001); opcodes[1001] = x;`. No idea why this was accepted, it's wrong.

Comment: The Contains() part is right but that's also already in the question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman There´s a bit more about this: the `Opcode` isn´t actually the index within the list, it is its value. While `opcodes.Add(1001)` works, `opcodes[1001] = x` doesn´t make any sense, because the 1001th element does probably  not exist.